# jQuery for selecting options that have no value, or particular text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have selects which all have a top option with text "All" and no value, but I need to write some code that works on all *other* options in these selects.

I have code as follow that works, but I'd rather do away with the conditional on the second line.  I did try using jQuery's ':not' selector but couldn't figure out how to configure it for missing/null/undefined value.  Would it best if I explicitly set value to the empty string "" and then use :not?

```
_.each($(select).find('option'), function(option) {
    if (optionVal = $(option).val()) {
```

Please excuse my usage of _.each instead of jQuery's each, we'd rather stay consistent as we use underscore for lots more than just iterating over jQuery matched sets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you could use either:

```
$(select).find('option[value!=""]');
```

or

```
$(select).find('option:not([value=""])');
```

to return the options that are not `<option value="">All</option>`

If the first `option` is always the valueless option, you could also use:

```
$(select).find('option:not(:eq(0))')
```

to select all `option` elements that are not the `first-child`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude the first Option from every Select element, you can use `:not()` selector and `.find()` method:

```
$('select').find('option:not(:first)');
```

In case that you want to filter the Options that have value, you can use `.filter()` method:

```
$('select option').filter(function() {
   return $.trim(this.value).length;
});
```

Note for iterating through jQuery collections it's better to use jQuery's `.each()` method, otherwise you will lose the chainabilty that jQuery provides.

Comment: I think I like :not(:first) best, though I may accept one of the other answers, because they do seem to better address the question precisely as I worded it

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I avoid using attribute selectors in this case, as `value` in the DOM's eyes is actally a property not an attribute, apart from this, you are completely free to accept the answer that works best for you.

Comment: Good clarification!  Unfortunately I'd just accepted the other answer.  Had your comment been part of the answer I probably would have accepted yours.  At 58.5k though you're not hurting for rep ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(select).find('option[value]'); // selects all <option>s with value
```

If I unserstood the question correctly.

Comment: I like this one but unfortunately due to the way we're using _.template the options with no values are being generated as <option value> and they get returned using your approach :(

Comment: In that case I too would use pete's answer with [value!='']

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

**HTML:**

```
<select>
    <option>All</option>
    <option value>0</option>
    <option value=1>One</option>
    <option value=2>Two</option>
</select>
```

**JS:** This will return only last two options (One and Two)

```
$('select option').filter(function(){
    return this.hasAttribute('value') && this.value.length;
});
```

to filter the options for `missing/null/undefined` value. Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/s2MaE/1/).

Comment: Way too verbose though I haven't tried it so won't down-mod it

Comment: I think, you mentioned `missing/null/undefined`, this will filter the option that has no `value or value=''`.